# number of block accesses required, sql

Tags: sql, database, size, block, record

The CoolCaravan Company has a database which includes a table called Sites. Each record in the table has the following fields: 
SiteID: 10 bytes 
Description: 80 bytes 
Loction: 20 bytes 
Gridref: 10 bytes

Suppose that the table has 1,300 records and is physically stored in a
file on disk blocks. Each disk block has a size of 1,600 bytes. The file
is ordered on the attribute Description. Showing all working, calculate
the:

1. record size = 120
2. blocking factor = 10
3. number of blocks needed to store the whole file = 160
4. number of block accesses required, on average, to execute the
   following SQL query:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM Sites WHERE Description = 'Banff Links';
   ```
5. number of block accesses required, on average, to execute the
   following SQL query (assuming Gridref is unique):

   ```
   SELECT * FROM Sites WHERE Gridref = 'NJ689637';
   ```

I am studying for an exam and my notes aren't clear as to how to go about answering the last two parts of the question.

Comment: Please clarify: "Suppose that the table has 1,300 records and is physically stored in a file on disk blocks. Each disk block has a size of 1,600 bytes.". What is the total number of blocks in the table?

Comment: sorry i forgot to include the first part of the question: The CoolCaravan Company has a database which includes a table called Sites. Each record in the table has the following fields:
SiteID: 10 bytes
Description: 80 bytes @Alex
Loction: 20 bytes
Gridref: 10 bytes

Comment: Update your question with this info to make it easier for other users

Comment: If you know answers to first questions post them as well, someone may comment on them

Answer (score 0):

I was never good at answering these tests.
I would put: 
5. 160 (number of blocks) / 2
Table is not ordered by Gridref so worst case scenario you have to search whole table. Best case, you only read 1 block.
Because Gridref is unique (and assuming unique constraint is defined on the table), you stop searching as soon as you find a result.

I was going to give a go at Q4 as well but my answer was becoming really long and convoluted so I thought it is probably wrong.

Update:
I checked your answers to questions 2 and 3 against [Blocking factor in a DBMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859070/blocking-factor-in-a-dbms/19856856)
and they do not seem to be correct. According to the article they should be:

- 2. FLOOR( 1600 / 120 ) = 13
- 3. 1300 / 13 = 100

How did you calculate your answers?